# Creating a build file with Shenzhen and Xcode 6 fails

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, jenkins, xcode6

I'm trying to setup a Jenkins job which will allow me to automatically create and upload an .ipa file to Itunes Connect. I'm using Shenzhen for this but it fails and I get the following output:
     xcodebuild  build/workspace/Mobile-IOS/AdminPanel/AdminPanel.xcworkspace

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies

(1 failure)

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies

(1 failure)

I use the following command in terminal:

```
$ ipa build --workspace build/workspace/Mobile-IOS/AdminPanel/AdminPanel.xcworkspace --scheme AdminPanel --config DEBUG
```

ps: I tried both debug and release configs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is not a direct answer to your question, however, I've had problems with Shenzhen in the past as well. I since switched over to the [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) toolset. They have a tool called [GYM](https://github.com/fastlane/gym). You should check it out. It's incredibly easy to use.

Comment: I just read a little bit about fastlane. You use [GYM](https://github.com/fastlane/gym) for the build part and [deliver](https://github.com/KrauseFx/deliver) to upload it to Itunes Connect from what I understand, right?

Comment: I use GYM to run the build and create an IPA, then I use `Pilot` to upload to iTunesConnect.